# How to show logged on username in NodeJS/ExpressJS/Passport?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I want to display the username in case the user is logged in (`function 3`). Initially, I only had `function 1`. I've changed `function 1` into `function 2` in order to display the username of the logged in user. I am not sure if this is the right way to do this, because I don't know if I need parameters `res` and `next`, and function `next()`.  Any idea?

I am using `NodeJS`, `ExpressJS` and `Passport`

**1.**

```
function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    return next()
  } else {
    res.redirect('/login')
  }
}
```

**2.**

```
function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    return true
  }
  return false
}
```

**3.**

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  if (isLoggedIn) {
    res.render('index', {
      username: req.user.username
    })
  } else {
    res.render('index')
  }
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are pretty much doing the right but calling the method `isLoggedIn` like a variable. I have corrected the same below.

**2**.

```
function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    return true;
  }

  return false;
}
```

**3**.

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  if (isLoggedIn(req, res, next)) {
    res.render('index', {
      username: req.user.username
    });
  } else {
    res.render('index');
  }
});
```

Also, you can refactor the `isLoggedIn` method as below.

```
function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
    return req.isAuthenticated();
}
```

Comment: I see I forgot to add the parameters. Thank you very much! :)